# Замена ключей в объекте js

Tags: javascript

возникла проблема с удалением заказа и сохранением, например: было 3 заказа (1,2,3), удалили по порядку 1,2,3, через консоль смотрим, остается один заказ, хотя удалили все, если удалять с конца, 3,2,1 то всё хорошо.

https://jsfiddle.net/spoon100500/pa6847vu

```js
const setCartData = (data, key) => localStorage.setItem(data, key),
  getCartData = (key) => JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(key));

$('#wb_account_calcFontAwesomeIcon1').click(addToCart);

function addToCart() {
  let zak = getCartData('zakaz') || {};

  let numberZakaz = Object.keys(zak).length + 1;

  zak[numberZakaz] = [numberZakaz];

  localStorage.setItem('zakaz', JSON.stringify(zak));
  openCart();
};

function openCart() {
  let zakaz = getCartData('zakaz');
  if (zakaz !== null) {
    totalItems = '<table class="shopping_list table table-striped table-bordered table-hover table-sm table-responsive-xl text-center"><tr><th scope="col">№</th><th scope="col">Удалить</th></tr>';
    for (let items in zakaz) {
      totalItems += '<tr class="jqcart-tr" data-id="' + items + '">';
      totalItems += '<td class="align-middle">' + items + '</td>'; //Номер
      totalItems += '<td class="align-middle"><img class="deleteBusOut"></td>';
      totalItems += '</tr>';
    }
    totalItems += '</table>';
    cartCont = totalItems;
  }
  $("#account_calcLayoutGrid3 .col-1").html(cartCont);
};

$('#wb_account_calcLayoutGrid3').on('click', '.deleteBusOut', function() {
  let index = 1,
    cartData = getCartData('zakaz'),
    dataId = $(this).closest('.jqcart-tr').data('id');

  delete cartData[dataId];

  $(this).closest('.jqcart-tr').remove();

  cartData = Object.keys(cartData).reduce((res, key) => {
    if (key !== dataId.toString() && key !== dataId) {
      res[index] = cartData[key];
      index++;
    }
    return res;
  }, {});

  localStorage.setItem('zakaz', JSON.stringify(cartData));
});
console.log(getCartData('zakaz'));
```

```css
#wb_account_calcFontAwesomeIcon1 {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 45px;
  height: 45px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: transparent;
  background-image: none;
  border: 0px solid #245580;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  vertical-align: top;
  position: relative;
}

#account_calcFontAwesomeIcon1 {
  height: 45px;
  width: 45px;
}

#account_calcFontAwesomeIcon1 i {
  color: #000080;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 45px;
  line-height: 45px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 34px;
}

.fa {
  font: normal normal normal 14px/1 FontAwesome;
  text-rendering: auto;
}

.deleteBusOut:hover {
  background: url(https://санхаус2000.рф/calc/imagesbd/bush.png) no-repeat scroll center center transparent;
  border: 1px solid orange;
}

.deleteBusOut {
  border: 1px dotted #CCC;
  border-radius: 7px;
  height: 35px;
  width: 35px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: transparent url(https://санхаус2000.рф/calc/imagesbd/bus.png) no-repeat scroll center center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div id="wb_account_calcFontAwesomeIcon1">
  <a href="#">
    <div id="account_calcFontAwesomeIcon1"><i class="fa fa-plus-square-o"></i></div>
  </a>
</div>
<span>Добавить</span>
<div id="wb_account_calcLayoutGrid3">
  <div id="account_calcLayoutGrid3">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-1"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/spoon100500/pa6847vu  Не смог добавить ссылку сразу в вопрос, требует какие-то 4 отступа, что только не делал, не вставляется ссылка.

Comment: Добавьте код прям в вопрос. У вопроса есть кнопка "Редактировать".

Comment: если используются цифровые ключи, почему не используется массив?

Comment: Grundy можно пример с массивом объектов?

Answer (score 1):

После удаления элемента из списка, у вас идет пересчет элементов

```
if (key !== dataId.toString() && key !== dataId) {
  res[index] = cartData[key];
  index++;
}
```

Вполне возможно, нужно так:

```
if (key !== dataId.toString() && key !== dataId) {
  res[key] = cartData[key];
  //index++;
}
```

Comment: Ваше решение не работает.

Answer (score 1):

Проблема заключается в неверном подходе при удалении. Ключи в объекте `cartData` переписываются, а в разметке остаются прежними.

Эту проблему можно было бы избежать, если использовать вместо объекта массив. В этом случае удаление становится тривиальным с помощью [`splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) и получением нужного элемента с помощью [`.index`](https://api.jquery.com/index/), и переписывать ничего не надо, так как из разметки data-id уходит, а индексы в массиве поменяются автоматически.

```js
var ls = {};
const setCartData = (data, key) => ls[data] = key,
  getCartData = (key) => JSON.parse(ls[key] || null);

$('#wb_account_calcFontAwesomeIcon1').click(addToCart);

function addToCart() {
  let zak = getCartData('zakaz') || [];

  zak.push([zak.length + 1]);

  setCartData('zakaz', JSON.stringify(zak));
  openCart();
};

function openCart() {
  let zakaz = getCartData('zakaz');
  if (zakaz !== null) {
    totalItems = '<table class="shopping_list table table-striped table-bordered table-hover table-sm table-responsive-xl text-center"><thead><tr><th scope="col">№</th><th scope="col">Удалить</th></tr></thead>';
    for (var i = 0; i < zakaz.length; i++) {
      totalItems += '<tr class="jqcart-tr">';
      totalItems += '<td class="align-middle">' + (i + 1) + '</td>'; //Номер
      totalItems += '<td class="align-middle"><img class="deleteBusOut"></td>';
      totalItems += '</tr>';
    }
    totalItems += '</table>';
    cartCont = totalItems;
  }
  $("#account_calcLayoutGrid3 .col-1").html(cartCont);
};

$('#wb_account_calcLayoutGrid3').on('click', '.deleteBusOut', function() {
  let index = 1,
    cartData = getCartData('zakaz'),
    dataId = $(this).closest('.jqcart-tr').index();

  cartData.splice(dataId, 1);

  $(this).closest('.jqcart-tr').remove();

  setCartData('zakaz', JSON.stringify(cartData));
  console.log(getCartData('zakaz'));
});
console.log(getCartData('zakaz'));
```

```css
#wb_account_calcFontAwesomeIcon1 {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 45px;
  height: 45px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: transparent;
  background-image: none;
  border: 0px solid #245580;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  vertical-align: top;
  position: relative;
}

#account_calcFontAwesomeIcon1 {
  height: 45px;
  width: 45px;
}

#account_calcFontAwesomeIcon1 i {
  color: #000080;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 45px;
  line-height: 45px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 34px;
}

.fa {
  font: normal normal normal 14px/1 FontAwesome;
  text-rendering: auto;
}

.deleteBusOut:hover {
  background: url(https://санхаус2000.рф/calc/imagesbd/bush.png) no-repeat scroll center center transparent;
  border: 1px solid orange;
}

.deleteBusOut {
  border: 1px dotted #CCC;
  border-radius: 7px;
  height: 35px;
  width: 35px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: transparent url(https://санхаус2000.рф/calc/imagesbd/bus.png) no-repeat scroll center center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div id="wb_account_calcFontAwesomeIcon1">
  <a href="#">
    <div id="account_calcFontAwesomeIcon1"><i class="fa fa-plus-square-o"></i></div>
  </a>
</div>
<span>Добавить</span>
<div id="wb_account_calcLayoutGrid3">
  <div id="account_calcLayoutGrid3">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-1"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Либо просто не заниматься ерундой и не переписывать объект на каждом удалении:

```js
var ls = {};
const setCartData = (data, key) => ls[data] = key,
  getCartData = (key) => JSON.parse(ls[key] || null);

$('#wb_account_calcFontAwesomeIcon1').click(addToCart);

function addToCart() {
  let zak = getCartData('zakaz') || {};

  let numberZakaz = Object.keys(zak).length + 1;

  zak[numberZakaz] = [numberZakaz];

  setCartData('zakaz', JSON.stringify(zak));
  openCart();
};

function openCart() {
  let zakaz = getCartData('zakaz');
  if (zakaz !== null) {
    totalItems = '<table class="shopping_list table table-striped table-bordered table-hover table-sm table-responsive-xl text-center"><tr><th scope="col">№</th><th scope="col">Удалить</th></tr>';
    for (let items in zakaz) {
      totalItems += '<tr class="jqcart-tr" data-id="' + items + '">';
      totalItems += '<td class="align-middle">' + items + '</td>'; //Номер
      totalItems += '<td class="align-middle"><img class="deleteBusOut"></td>';
      totalItems += '</tr>';
    }
    totalItems += '</table>';
    cartCont = totalItems;
  }
  $("#account_calcLayoutGrid3 .col-1").html(cartCont);
};

$('#wb_account_calcLayoutGrid3').on('click', '.deleteBusOut', function() {
  let index = 1,
    cartData = getCartData('zakaz'),
    dataId = $(this).closest('.jqcart-tr').data('id');

  delete cartData[dataId];

  $(this).closest('.jqcart-tr').remove();

  setCartData('zakaz', JSON.stringify(cartData));
  console.log(getCartData('zakaz'));
});
console.log(getCartData('zakaz'));
```

```css
#wb_account_calcFontAwesomeIcon1 {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 45px;
  height: 45px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: transparent;
  background-image: none;
  border: 0px solid #245580;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  vertical-align: top;
  position: relative;
}

#account_calcFontAwesomeIcon1 {
  height: 45px;
  width: 45px;
}

#account_calcFontAwesomeIcon1 i {
  color: #000080;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 45px;
  line-height: 45px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 34px;
}

.fa {
  font: normal normal normal 14px/1 FontAwesome;
  text-rendering: auto;
}

.deleteBusOut:hover {
  background: url(https://санхаус2000.рф/calc/imagesbd/bush.png) no-repeat scroll center center transparent;
  border: 1px solid orange;
}

.deleteBusOut {
  border: 1px dotted #CCC;
  border-radius: 7px;
  height: 35px;
  width: 35px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: transparent url(https://санхаус2000.рф/calc/imagesbd/bus.png) no-repeat scroll center center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div id="wb_account_calcFontAwesomeIcon1">
  <a href="#">
    <div id="account_calcFontAwesomeIcon1"><i class="fa fa-plus-square-o"></i></div>
  </a>
</div>
<span>Добавить</span>
<div id="wb_account_calcLayoutGrid3">
  <div id="account_calcLayoutGrid3">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-1"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Grundy спасибо, вы правы.

Comment: Почему то в локал не сохраняет https://jsfiddle.net/spoon100500/v7maLug8/

Comment: @spoon100500, да, я забыл добавить. Здесь в сниппетах localStorage нельзя использовать из-за настроек безопасности, поэтому я в твоих методах `setCartData` и `getCartData` просто заношу значения в объект. Замени их чтобы они в localStorage записывали и считывали, как они у тебя сейчас.

Comment: Если удалять не по порядку и записывать в локал, то потом не добавляются https://jsfiddle.net/spoon100500/Lrdtkao6/

Comment: @spoon100500, конечно, ты же в качестве ключа берешь текущее количество ключей

Comment: Тогда только через push?

Comment: @spoon100500, так будет проще всего. Либо выбрать для ключа что-то более уникальное чем текущее количество ключей

Answer (score 0):

Добавляю через push, удаляю так:

```js
$('#wb_account_calcLayoutGrid3').on('click', '.deleteBusOut', function() {
let cartData = getCartData('zakaz'),
    dataId = $(this).closest('.jqcart-tr').data('id'); //получаем data-id удаляемого изделия
  
$(this).closest('.jqcart-tr').remove(); //удаляем из разметки
delete cartData[dataId]; //удаляем этот заказ из хранилища 
  
let newArr = cartData.filter(Boolean);//Удаляем дыры в массиве

newArr.forEach(function(item, i) {//Делаем нумерацию заказа с 1
newArr[i][0] = i + 1;
});
 
localStorage.setItem('zakaz', JSON.stringify(newArr));
});
```

Comment: вместо delete + filter мог просто filter использовать в котором делать проверку. Зачем нужен foreach - непонятно